List all files and folders and permissions in cmd
Currently I need to make a list of all files and all folders and who has access to them.
I have already made a list of items with the dir /b/s/o, but I do not have the access list for each file/folder
list of permissions
If there is a way to combine the dir command with another to create this list of access and each item, I would appreciate it.

You can use icacls.exe to display or modify discretionary access control lists (DACLs) on specified files.
Create a batch file like file_permissions.bat and paste following
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o') do (

    icacls "%%a" >> access_list.txt

)

Does this help?

Nice, though note that it's more robust and efficient to apply the output redirection to the entire loop, which requires enclosing it in (...): (for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o') do ( icacls "%%a" )) > access_list.txt

when i run the bat the exit every item have that text "Successfully processed 1 files; failed to process 0 files", can i remove then?

Since this question is tagged with powershell, the equivalent of icacls is Get-Acl and Set-Acl. It is not clear what output is needed. Something like this will produce what icacls <filename> would produce.
Get-ChildItem -Path $Env:USERPROFILE/test.txt |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Filename = $_.FullName
        $Accounts = ((Get-Acl -Path $Filename).AccessToString) -split '\n'
        foreach ($Account in $Accounts) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Filename = $Filename
                Account = $Account
            }
        }
    }

Filename              Account
--------              -------
C:\Users\lit\test.txt NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
C:\Users\lit\test.txt BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
C:\Users\lit\test.txt ZEP001\lit Allow  FullControl

All that needs to be done is to add an output destination. This produces a CSV file that can easily be opened as a spreadsheet.
$PathToSearch = 'R:\'
$OutputFile = "$Env:USERPROFILE/access_list.csv"

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $PathToSearch |
    ForEach-Object {
        $Filename = $_.FullName
        $Accounts = ((Get-Acl -Path $Filename).AccessToString) -split '\n'
        foreach ($Account in $Accounts) {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                Filename = $Filename
                Account = $Account
            }
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile


if a want to scan all files and directories and sub directories from R:\ and export in a txt how can i change the script to do that task?

thanks that help a lot, i upgrade some fields to show more information
code  Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $PathToSearch | ForEach-Object { $Filename = $_.FullName $FileSize = $_.Length $LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime $Owner = (Get-Acl -Path $Filename).Owner $Accounts = ((Get-Acl -Path $Filename).AccessToString) -split '\n' foreach ($Account in $Accounts) { [PSCustomObject]@{ Filename = $Filename FileSize = $FileSize LastWriteTime = $LastWriteTime Owner = $Owner Account = $Account
